# Spring Integration - JMS Output Adapter - Send object as String using message converter

Tags: spring-integration

**Issue:** message-converter on JMS outbound-channel-adapter is sending the object I unMarshall  as bytes instead of JMS TextMessage. Is it possible to set the message-converter to explicitly tell it to send as JMS TextMessage and not bytes? I thought of putting a transformer step in-between the splitter and outbound that will just return a string but seems inefficient.

**Reference Documentation:**
[JMS Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html)

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd">


        <int:chain id="fooChain" input-channel="requestChannel">    

            <!-- Performs processing action - Returns List<Foo> objects -->
            <int:service-activator ref="fooListener" method="processFoo"/>

            <int:splitter />

            <!-- Covert messages and send to mq queue -->       
            <jms:outbound-channel-adapter 
                id="fooRequestsChannel"
                destination="externalAppRequestQueue"
                message-converter="fooMessageConverter">
            </jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

        </int:chain> 


        <bean id="oxmFooMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
              <property name="marshaller" ref="fooMarshaller" />
              <property name="unmarshaller" ref="fooMarshaller" />
               <!-- SOLUTION ADDED HERE: START --> 
              <property name="targetType" value="TEXT"/>
               <!-- SOLUTION ADDED HERE: END-->
        </bean>


         <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="fooMarshaller">  
            <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.test.foo" />
         </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

    </beans>
```

**Solution:**

Add the following property to oxmFooMessageConverter above. The JMS message will be sent as TEXT string to the queue and not bytes. Above example updated.

```
<property name="targetType" value="TEXT"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M-m-m. What is the question? You did that already: `message-converter="fooMessageConverter"`.

What is a problem do you have ?

The `MarshallingMessageConverter` has an option if you want `String`:

```
/**
 * Specify whether {@link #toMessage(Object, Session)} should marshal to
 * a {@link BytesMessage} or a {@link TextMessage}.
 * <p>The default is {@link MessageType#BYTES}, i.e. this converter marshals
 * to a {@link BytesMessage}. Note that the default version of this converter
 * supports {@link MessageType#BYTES} and {@link MessageType#TEXT} only.
 * @see MessageType#BYTES
 * @see MessageType#TEXT
 */
public void setTargetType(MessageType targetType) {
    Assert.notNull(targetType, "MessageType must not be null");
    this.targetType = targetType;
}
```

Comment: The problem I have is that in the current example above. It is sending my object to the queue as in bytes format and not string? A receiving application is throwing an error saying it is not in a JMS Text Message Format, but rather bytes. Reading the spring documentation it sounds like that I have to send my a String object to the output adapter to send as JMS Text Message.

Comment: OK. Does `MarshallingMessageConverter .setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT)` help you? Why don't you pay attention to that my explanation ?

Comment: Yes that worked. Specifying the property type for target type for value of text.